# Set caption above figure and setting right numbering

Tags: numbering, captions

my problem is that with the following preamble and command I get a figure that is has a caption below the figure and its number is 2 in the caption.

Notice that I already researched a lot but could not find a solution. Also notice that in my title page (which I do not include here) I inserted a figure with subfigures but set as `\begin{figure*}` so that it is not affecting by numbering. However, the first figure that I include has the number 2 in the caption! Why is that?

```
\documentclass[11pt, fleqn, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} %Grafik
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{placeins}

\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{lmargin=2.1cm, rmargin=2.1cm, tmargin=2.1cm, bmargin=2.1cm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\spacing{1.5}
\usepackage[font=normalsize]{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top,footposition=caption}
\captionsetup[table]{footfont=footnotesize}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength\mathindent{0pt}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
%---------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}

\begin{titlepage}
%some title
\end{titlepage
\newpage
\shipout\null
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section*{Problem 1}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
\begin{itemize}
bla bla bla text
some tables 
\FloatBarrier
\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{Curves}
\label{Figure 1}
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Rplot}

\end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: I can't run your MWE successfuly (e.g., there is no `\end{document}` and "File Rplot not found" and other error messages). Please supply a MINIMAL Working Example that is minimal and does compile. The majority of code in your example has nothing to do with your stated problem.

Comment: Your example is far from *minimal*. Indeed it loads `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` twice and there is no `\end` for `figure` and `document`.

Comment: Off-topic: `amssymb` loads `amsfonts`, and `amsmath` loads both `amstext` and `amsopn`, so these three "subsidiary" packages aren't needed.

Comment: `figure*` has nothing to do with numbering.  The starred form indicates a full-width figure (at the top) on a multi-column page.  The caption will appear wherever you insert `\caption` -- move it to just before `\end{figure}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need the command `\includegraphics` to insert figures. The `figure` environment will only count the number of "figures" **if** there is a `\caption` inside it.

The following example shows the concept and some variations you might use.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Above}
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

No caption.
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

No figure environment. Text before.

\includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-c}

Text after.

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Below}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since I needed to keep two figures side by side in the title page and thus I was "forced" to use ```\begin{figure}``` with ```\begin{subfigures}``` after it and thus I  could not use only the ```\includegraphics``` command alone, I solve my issue simply using:
```\setcounter{figure}{0}```
and it worked. But your answer worked too in the case of setting the caption above the figures.

Comment: I'm glad to help @Matteo. I'm still a little bit curious with your "forced". `\includegraphics` works inside `\begin{titlepage}`. I would assume "forced" means someone outside telling you to use some syntax *because ... YES* and it is a constraint you cannot remove.

Comment: well I must say I am not an expert with LateX. I needed to put two pictures side by side in the title page and the only way I know hoe to do that is to use something like ```\begin{figure} ``` and then use ```subfigure```. And that was in fact the origin of the picture in the main body of the document starting from 2 instead of 1

Comment: Understood. In this case, I would recommend to read a little bit of the "MWE philosophy" at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example and http://minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html. Every time you face a new issue, try to isolate it. When asking for help, show a MWE and describe it. When you give examples with many other things, it is difficult to clearly identify the problem. Example: You might have a issue because some packages interfere with each other, but you ask about something that is not exactly related ... and well, it gets difficult to give good advice.